# Java Android:Add array 15times in one second How?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, handler

I want to add array 15 times in one second. I have used Timer, Countdowntimer, handler but not works on  Button Action.Down and Action.Move. Any help?

```
ArrayList<Integer> Xpos;
ArrayList<Integer> Ypos;
ArrayList<String> MarkerSelected;
private Handler handlerXYPos = new Handler();
Runnable runnableXYPos = null;



case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
handlerXYPos.post(runnableXYPos);   
break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
handlerXYPos.removeCallbacks(runnableXYPos);
break;


//=== case drag
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
handlerXYPos.post(runnableXYPos);
break;
```

This runnable executes 15frames

```
runnableXYPos = new Runnable() {  

                @Override  
                public void run() 
                {  

                     Xpos.add(xP);
                     Ypos.add(yP);
                     MarkerSelected.add(MarkerName);
                     handlerXYPos.postDelayed(runnableXYPos, 66);  //convert 15 in milisec = 66


                }  
            };
```

This code works when I just put down button press it sometimes add correct amount of values, but when I drag the finger it adds extra values.

Comment: Add logs in each Motion event case and you will figure out how it works.

Answer (score 2):

When you drag following things hapen

```
1) MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN called once when you press to start drag

2) MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE is called several times depending on your drag

3) MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: will get called once when you release to finish drag
```

So no need to write the code inside MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure thar it is solution, but try to do nothink in action move:

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:    
         // handlerXYPos.post(runnableXYPos);      
        break;
```

Comment: Right, but when I release the button, ActionUp removes this handler. This saves very less data.

Comment: Don't remove callback in action_up. Remove callback in callback when it is needed.

Comment: can you please show me how to remove this in call back??